# Is there a Lua string.find without pattern

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I apply a function, but looks so bad.

```
function find_without_pattern(s1,s2)
    for i =1,#s1-#s2+1 do
        local t = string.sub(s1,i,#s2+i-1)
        if t == s2 then
            return i,i+#s2-1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `string.find` method provides an optional 4th parameter to enforce a [plaintext search](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find) by itself.

For example:

```
string.find("he#.*o", "e#.*o", 1, true)
```

will give you the correct results.

Quoting the Lua manual pages:

> `string.find (s, pattern [, init [, plain]])`
>
> A value of `true` as a fourth, optional argument `plain` turns off the pattern matching facilities, so the function does a plain "find substring" operation, with no characters in pattern being considered magic. Note that if `plain` is given, then `init` must be given as well.

Comment: Nice, turns out I did the unnecessary work. I also edited your answer since I've deleted mine.